# UDF Returning Table IN DB2

Tags: db2, user-defined-functions

I was creating the UDF (user defined function) that returns Table in DB2.
Returning Table in this manner:

```
RETURNS TABLE(ID INTEGER,CurrencyCode VARCHAR(255),VALUES INTEGER)
```

But I am getting this error while creating the function:

> SQL0628N Multiple or conflicting keywords involving the "RETURNS
>   TABLE" clause are present.

How to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why is this question tagged "java"? I assume it is a function in SQL. Not sure, but `VALUES` is a keyword and could cause the error. Please post the whole function

Comment: Formatted code and error message

Comment: Please provide full `create function` statement.